# Magnolia RSSAggregator not picking up images?

Tags: rss, content-management-system, magnolia

I'm using RSSAggregator to syndicate content from my Magnolia page. However the module is not picking up images on my page - just the header and text. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

See http://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MGNLRSSAGG-40

You will also find a patch there.